# 'import pyodbc' leads to 'No module named pyodbc '

Tags: python

I recently ran `pip install pyodbc`. Which says it installed pyodbc successfully on the cmd.

However when I do `import pyodbc` in IDLE I receive an error saying 'No module named pyodbc'.

It seems only two files have been installed when I ran `pip install pyodbc`.

The two files:

pyodbc-4.0.26.dist-info

pyodbc.cp36-win32.pyd

VERSION of Python:
Python 3.6.3

Complete Error Message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7doJI.png)

How do I resolve this issue? Any help would be much appreciated, I'm new to python and this is quite frustrating.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Show the complete error message.

Comment: Did you try upgrading? `pip install --upgrade pyodbc`?

Comment: I just tried upgrading and it says 'Requirement already up-to-date'

Comment: What happens when you do `setup.py install`?

Comment: Do I just run 'setup.py install' on the cmd?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions installed? Your error message implies it is looking into Python 3.7.

Comment: Check sys.path and confirm pyodbc is in the path. To do so "import sys" and then print(sys.path) to print path list

Comment: @RebornCodeLover Actually after checking I do believe I have another version of python on that vm. Python 3.7.2

Comment: @RebornCodeLover Okay I checked the paths using ur method and it seems there are several paths.

Comment: @RebornCodeLover In some of the paths, the two files I mentioned earlier when installing pyodbc is in those paths but no file named pyodbc

Comment: I've had the same issue a few weeks back. I tried installing libraries using cmd for IDLE for python 3.7 but cmd was installing for my anaconda version of python 3.6.

Comment: @manshu Oh I see, I'll have a look into that but I already installed 3 other libraries. bs4, requests and smtplib. Those installed fine and I was able to import them without an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files that installed are fine. *.pyd is compiled library (see https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll).

Issues that may cause this:

1. IDLE running main python installation and you installed the package in virtual environment
2. You have several installations of python e.g. python 3.x alongside python 2.x

I think first of all try to run all the steps from the same cmd:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> pip install pyodbc
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/00/7115c072d4d01da4feee740cf5d964b4367ba0f9843d334d64ef77fd2baa/pyodbc-4.0.26-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
Successfully installed pyodbc-4.0.26

# now just run python interpreter

PS C:\Windows\system32> python
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
# no error
```

This should work...

And then try to understand if you have several virtualenvs or python instalations.
You can check which python IDLE run, by right click on it's shortcut and "open file location" for example

Comment: Thank you Leon! Yup got no error when I tried it that way. I have both serveral virtual machines and python installations lol. I will do some troubleshooting on that now but thanks again for helping me understand the problem!