# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc' - Azure Batch - Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, azure, ubuntu, azure-batch

I am trying to run a Python job using a VM on Azure Batch, utilizing the Python package Pyodbc. However I am unable to install it correctly (obviously) as run into `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'`. I used the following command (start task) to install the ODBC driver on my VM (Ubuntu) and installation works fine:

```
/bin/bash -c 'sudo -H apt-get -y update && 
sudo -H dpkg --configure -a && 
sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-pip && 
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip && 
sudo -H su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo -H apt-get update
sudo -H ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
sudo -H apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev && 
sudo -H pip3 install pandas &&
sudo -H pip3 -H install egg && 
sudo -H pip3 -H install azure-storage-common && 
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc &&
sudo -H pip3 install azure-storage-blob'
```

The wierd part is that I can run `import pandas` and the other packages without any problem. Can someone help me out?

guide for installing ODBC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You either might have multiple versions of Python installed alongside each other or are installing the module in one but running the script in another environment.

Some similar issues:

- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc' when importing pyodbc into py script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085191/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pyodbc-when-importing-pyodbc-into-py-scri)
- ['import pyodbc' leads to 'No module named pyodbc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55216597/import-pyodbc-leads-to-no-module-named-pyodbc)
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc' #768](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/768)

It is always advisable to run your Python code in context of a virtual environment, so it runs in the environment's exact context with specific versions of every library, that can help with avoiding such errors.